# How to convert date from format like "Mon,YYYY" in string to format like "dd-mm-yyyy"

Tags: vb.net

I have a string variable which stores date value `Jan,2014` for January, 2014 and `Feb,2014` for Feburary 2014 but I now want to convert it in format like `01-01-2014` for January and `01-02-2014` for Feburary. I want the first date of these months.

And also I want to compare this month wether this month lies in the past 36 months from todays month.

Eg.

> Todays month is December 2014 so I want to check if the provided month lies in between December 2011 and December 2014 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim inDate As String = "Jan,2014" '<-- be your input string
Dim convertedDate As Date = CDate(inDate )'<-- be the required output as date datatype
```

If you want the output as a string variable then you can use like this:

```
 Dim convertedDate As String = CDate(s).ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim temp As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Jan,2014", "MMM,yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim result As String = temp.ToString("01-MM-yyyy")
Dim isRecent As Boolean = temp > Today.AddMonths(-36).AddDays(-1 * (Today.Day - 1))
```